# Как использовать в продакшене результат обучения модели?

Tags: python

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ANqJfKoqZtbjvPCAdbyPvmESmvVfeqIe/view?usp=sharing
Есть датасет с полями: дата, остаток, сумма продаж, количество(целевая переменная). Если создавать для обучения модели обучающую и тестовую выборки, то как результат обучения predict применить на практике в продакшене, ведь в реальных условиях для предсказания не будет ничего кроме даты, а в тестовую выборку подаются остаток, сумма продаж?

Comment: если модель обучалась на трех столбцах то и для предсказания ей надо подавать те же столбцы на вход...

Comment: Значит в 2 неизвестных столбцах (остаток, сумма продаж )надо подставлять скользящее среднее, которое вычисляется по прошлым данным ? Или сделать 3 целевые переменные  остаток, сумма продаж, количество?

Comment: сразу на такой вопрос не ответишь... Надо пробовать разные модели, потом сравнивать, потом делать тонкую настройку гиперпараметров, и т.д. и т.п. )

Comment: три целевые переменные не подошло, а как подставить скользящее среднее?

Comment: я думаю стоит открыть вопрос с небольшим примером данных и результатом, который вы хотите получить

Comment: Добавила вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092943/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb