# Как решить задачу алгоритма машинного обучения временного ряда с несколькими целевыми переменными y1, y2?

Tags: python

Есть датасет
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ANqJfKoqZtbjvPCAdbyPvmESmvVfeqIe/view?usp=sharing с полями: дата, остаток, сумма продаж, количество(целевая переменная). Если создавать для обучения модели обучающую и тестовую выборки, то как результат обучения predict применить на практике в продакшене, ведь в реальных условиях для предсказания не будет ничего кроме даты, а в тестовую выборку подаются остаток, сумма продаж.
Поэтому для разбора ситуации создан датасет

```
dataset = np.array( 
    [['01.01.2001',1, 100, 1000], 
    ['02.01.2001', 2, 500, 3000], 
    ['03.01.2001', 3, 1500, 5000], 
    ['04.01.2001',4, 3500, 8000], 
    ['05.01.2001',5, 5000, 6500], 
    ['06.01.2001',6, 6000, 7000], 
    ['07.01.2001',7, 8000, 15000], 
    ['08.01.2001',8, 9500, 20000], 
    ['09.01.2001',9, 12000, 21000], 
    ['10.01.2001',10, 14000, 25000], 
    ['11.01.2001',11, 15500, 27000], 
    ['12.01.2001',12, 16500, 30000], 
    ['13.01.2001',13, 25000, 52000], 
    ['14.01.2001',14, 30000, 80000] 
    ]) 
    X = dataset[:, 1:2].astype(int)  

    # print X 
    print(X) 
    [[ 1]
     [ 2]
     [ 3]
     [ 4]
     [ 5]
     [ 6]
     [ 7]
     [ 8]
     [ 9]
     [10]
     [11]
     [12]
     [13]
     [14]]
    y = dataset[:, 2:4].astype(int)  

    # print y 
    print(y) 
    [[  100  1000]
     [  500  3000]
     [ 1500  5000]
     [ 3500  8000]
     [ 5000  6500]
     [ 6000  7000]
     [ 8000 15000]
     [ 9500 20000]
     [12000 21000]
     [14000 25000]
     [15500 27000]
     [16500 30000]
     [25000 52000]
     [30000 80000]]
```

Здесь датасет с 4 полями: дата, входная переменная, 2 выходные переменные.
Как создать временной ряд с мульти output с 2 целевыми переменными. Это нужно, чтобы 
после обучения по алгоритму машинного обучения,  можно было ввести только дату,
а на выходе получить количество и сумму. За прошлый период обе переменные - количество и сумма известны. 
Вариант задания массива из двух переменных со сдвигом по лагам от 7 до 30(за неделю
надо предсказывать) не удался. Теперь рассматриваю вариант подстановки в поле суммы скользящего среднего за последнюю неделю, но не знаю как реализовать. Целевая переменная, которая нужна - одна - количество продаж.